# "dpkg-divert: error: rename involves overwriting `protocol.txt' with different file `protocol-precise.txt'" while upgrading xorg

Tags: apt

This happen after the download of Ubuntu 13.04 and I can't even download stuff because of this problem:

```
root@Viktor-Dator:/home/viktor# sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
xserver-common-lts-raring
The following packages have been kept back:
libboost-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-regex-dev libboost-system-dev
libboost-thread-dev
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 1,646 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 264683 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing xserver-common-lts-raring ...
Removing 'diversion of /usr/lib/xorg/protocol.txt to /usr/lib/xorg/protocol-precise.txt by xserver-common-lts-raring'
dpkg-divert: error: rename involves overwriting `/usr/lib/xorg/protocol.txt' with
different file `/usr/lib/xorg/protocol-precise.txt', not allowed
dpkg: error processing xserver-common-lts-raring (--remove):
subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:
xserver-common-lts-raring
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@Viktor-Dator:/home/viktor#
```

Output off sudo apt-get check

```
viktor@Viktor-Dator:~$ sudo apt-get check
[sudo] password for viktor: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
viktor@Viktor-Dator:~$
```

Comment: @Lucio: No, it's a different error

Answer (score 1):

Ok, since apparently is not any package that when bad, we must remove it manually without the help of apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -s --reinstall install xserver-common
sudo dpkg --purge --force-all xserver-common-lts-raring
sudo apt-get --reinstall install xserver-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Now you may want to unhold the package that you have hold:

```
sudo dpkg --set-selections < echo "libboost-dev install"
sudo dpkg --set-selections < echo "libboost-filesystem-dev install"
sudo dpkg --set-selections < echo "libboost-regex-dev install"
sudo dpkg --set-selections < echo "libboost-system-dev install"
sudo dpkg --set-selections < echo "libboost-thread-dev install"
```

Do a final `sudo apt-get check` to verify that everything is ok.

Answer (score -1):

first you need to clear your console so just try this command that will clear your fault dependency in your system. and you can install any plugin again.

```
sudo dpkg -r libjack-jackd2-0
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

The commands remove the offending file, attempts to fix the broken dependency and updates your system.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see that package anywhere giving problems.